# How to replace all tr tags with th tags

Tags: jquery, regex, html-table

I have a table like that:

```
<thead>    
    <tr class="row-2"><tr>
    <tr class="row-3">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-4">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-5">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-6">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-7"><tr>
    <tr class="row-8">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-9">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-10">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-11">..<tr>
</thead>
```

How can I replace all tr tags with th tag inside thead tag, using jQuery?

Comment: For anyone still coming across this question, it is a misunderstanding of the `th` tag. `<th>` is a tag for a _cell_, *not* a _row_ like `<tr>`. `<thead>` still contains `<tr>` rows; it is the rows' `<td>` tags that should be changed to `<th>` tags, i.e. `<thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the tables html then [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) all occurences or tr (see [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) for more info) with th. You could probably set the <thead> to have an id and access that.

```
$('#tableId').html($('#tableId').html().replace(/tr/gi, 'th'));
```

This will change all tr's in the entire table to th.

**EDIT**
For better performance thanks to jAndy.

```
$('#mytable').find('tr').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.replaceWith('<th class="' + this.className + '">' + $this.text() + '</th>');
});
```

Is .find() faster than $('#mytable > tr')?

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. I'm checking this answer as right in two minutes.

Comment: Note that both of these solutions may have serious drawbacks for some use cases. Both solutions will obliterate any events on the `<tr>` elements or their descendants, and the second solution will obliterate child elements.

Comment: @eyelidlessness: you are right. It's probably a good idea to `.clone()` the element or copy all `.data()` expandos.